# linux + files under - /var/spool/clientmqeueue

Tags: linux

please advice if I need to make some other actions after

```
chkconfig --level 5 sendmail off ?
chkconfig --level 6 sendmail off ?
```

in order to activate the new configuration ? ( affect the configuration )

example:

```
 chkconfig --list sendmail
 sendmail       0:off 1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:on  6:on


 chkconfig --level 5 sendmail off
 chkconfig --level 5 sendmail off


 chkconfig --list sendmail
 sendmail       0:off 1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

restart the sendmail service or maybe reboot the machine ???

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with its title, or with `/var/spool/clientmqeueue` (which is spelled wrong).

Comment: and the solution has nothing to do with `chkconfig`.

Comment: do you mean the chkconfig on all level off not stop the files creation under /var/spool/clientmqeueue ? , my target is to disable the files creation

Comment: Sendmail (not the service; when invoked by a user or program to send a message) puts messages there until they're successfully sent. What is this machine supposed to be doing? Who/what is sending messages? Why do you not want files in `clientmqueue`? Would it be better to get sendmail running *correctly* so that messages are sent properly and `clientmqueue` doesn't accumulate?

Comment: I not want to get files to clientmqueue because this folder is huge capacity and I only want to disable the file creation under this directory , what your suggestion ?

Comment: please advice if  stoping the sendmail proccess will stop to create files under clientmqueue folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sendmail` is running and you're reconfiguring it not to run for the current run level, `chkconfig` will not shut it down, so you would need to run something like `service sendmail stop`. You do not need to reboot.

Comment: why `stop` ? you want to restart/reload

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Not if he's turning sendmail `off` with `chkconfig`...?

Comment: he probably doesn't know what he's doing...

Comment: what I want is to disable the files creation under /var/spool/clientmqeueue

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't either, but I was directly answering the question in his OP ("what do I have to do to make this change take effect...")